# AngularJs Service access to service context from within then() context

Tags: angularjs

I'm probably making a beginners mistake. I'm trying to figure out how to access a function or variable in the `this` context of a service, while within the `then()` portion of a promise.

Here's some example code:

```
ndtApp.service("userService", ['$http',
function($http){

    this.saveLoginInfo = function(data){
        //do some stuff here.
    }

    this.login = function(){
        //Login
        $http.get('http://example.com/userlogin').then(
            function(data){
                this.saveLoginInfo(data);
                //This won't work because 'this' from here is 'window' rather than the service.
            },
            function(data){
                //error handling
            });
    }

}]);
```

How do I reach the `saveLoginInfo` function?

Comment: John Papa suggests [using a variable to capture `this` for this very reason](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y032).

Comment: That's a great read, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enter a function in JS the context changes to the current function. You can assign `this` to a veriable to resolve the scope.

```
ndtApp.service("userService", ['$http',
function($http){
var self = this;
self.saveLoginInfo = function(data){
    //do some stuff here.
}

self.login = function(){
    //Login
    $http.get('http://example.com/userlogin').then(
        function(data){
            self.saveLoginInfo(data);
            //This won't work because 'this' from here is 'window' rather than the service.
        },
        function(data){
            //error handling
        });
}

}]);
```

Comment: This did definitely work. Follow up question: Is the `self` now defined in `window`? Is that not a problem / something messy we should avoid?

Comment: @Coo self is defined in the context of the service. It will be available to any function you define within the service. I recommend reading the style guide sbat linked. It's a great resource

Comment: Thanks for that! I did read the style guide which has led me to start using IIFE's which solved my pollution problem.